# prove: transformation T(x, y, z)=(2x, y)

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I am familiar with the process of proving linearity but I haven't seen an example of $\mathbb{R^3}>\mathbb{R^2}$ with $\mathrm{T}(x, y, z)=(2x, y)$.

Should I go ahead, start with this $> (2(x1+x2), (y1+y2))$ and then continue? Or am I neglecting the $z$ coordinate?

Comment: Start from the definition of linearity and work deductively

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same as the case of both the domain and the image being of the same dimension.

Let $\lambda(x_1+x_2, y_1 + y_2, z_1 + z_2) \in \mathbb D_T, \lambda \in \mathbb R$. Then, plug this in your transformation and use the vector properties to prove that it's just a linear combination of each while also proving the scalar multiplication property.

Comment: So when I plug that into my transformation, since there is no z coordinate, there will be no z1 + z2? or do I still just determine linearity with the z coordinate still there?

Comment: @Aaron As simple as you mentioned, there will be no $z$ coordinate !

Comment: awesome. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Aaron If my answer was helpful you can vote up with the arrows on the left and mark the answer as accepted by using the tick button below the vote buttons. Glad I helped !